# Flexi Task; multiple projects need approved

Tags: workflow, tasks

How our process works: We have a meeting and review  various projects. Each stakeholder needs to approve each project. I am attempting to move this manual process into a work flow.

Here is my idea: I start with querying the list and pulling in the projects that will need approved that day into a collection. There can be 1-20 projects at any given point needing approval. I initiate a for each, in which I declare them as records to avoid further editing prior to the approval process. I then assign a flexi task....there lies the problem. I don't know if this will work.

Will I be able to know which project is associated with each outcome variable?

Should I have a spin off that starts a new workflow; if so; how can I bring the data all back together?

Will each project send off its own flexi-task?

Desired end result: Send an e-mail notification with a list of all the projects for that day, their approval (or lack thereof) and the comments for each. I know how to build the table and pull everything together...

I am not sure if the for each-flexi task will work the way I need it to. I am open to suggestions.